# Working with dynamic data with Azure DocumentDB and MVC5

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Azure DocumentDB using dynamic data types, i.e., I do not predefine any classes for the data I'm working with.  I'm querying my DocumentDb database/collection using calls of the form:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), query).ToArray();
```

The objects that get returned seem to be of type Micrsoft.Azure.Documents.QueryResult.

When the query is included as part of an MVC action, when the results are passed back to the client they become empty objects.

I was expecting to get 'dynamic' data back which would serialize just fine as part of the JsonResponse.

What do I need to do to convert each Micrsoft.Azure.Documents.QueryResult to dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I tried to build my MVC Web Application and I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned.

> I was expecting to get 'dynamic' data back which would serialize just fine as part of the JsonResponse.

You could leverage the following code:

```
var results=client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), query).ToArray();
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results), "application/json");
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Excellent - that worked great.  Many thanks.  As a follow-up, with this approach the DocumentDb specific fields, such as _attach, _etag, _rid, _self and _ts are also serialized (as you show in your screenshot).  Any thoughts on how best these could get excluded/removed?

Comment: You could leverage a custom [IContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) that only serializes the properties based on your scenario (exclude the properties with the name _attach,_etag,_rid,etc.), for more details, you could refer to this [tutorial(http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomContractResolver.htm).